# Unit test a web service is compilable

Tags: asp.net, web-services, unit-testing

As our ASP.NET web service (asmx file) develops over time we sometimes get into a conflict of names returned by various methods of the web service. For example I could write a method that returns a Task class which has an enumeration Status and then after some time add a method returning a WorkOrder class which also has a Status enumeration. I know that best practice is to name the enumerations TaskStatus and WorkOrderStatus but assume this cannot be done and both enumerations are called Status and are declared inside their respective class. When trying to access the web service I will get an exception that there is a naming conflict of the Status enumeration.

I want to create a unit test that will catch this naming conflict. Our web service is unit tested but that only tests the GetTask and GetWorkOrder methods as a function that returns a class. It does not test the fact that ASP.NET is unable to generate a WSDL for the web service. The unit test should try to generate the WSDL just like ASP.NET does and see if the generation succeeded or not

I have a Web application project running the actual web service and another unit test project referencing (*not* web referencing) the web service project.

Any pointers/samples would be appreciated

Comment: do you mean *enumeration* when you say *enumerator*?

Comment: changed in the question. Thanks